# "Раз" подчинительный союз?

Tags: грамотная-речь, союзы, спп

Правильно я понимаю, что "раз" может быть подчинительным союзом? В смысле "поскольку", "уж если".

Например: *Раз ты принёс столько вкусного, придётся поесть.*

Или правильно только "раз уж"? Опускать "уж" неправильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Союз **РАЗ** является подчинительным условным союзом. Вот что написано в "Русской корпусной грамматике".

Список условных союзов: *если, если бы, если б, **раз**, ли, коль скоро, ежели (бы, б), коли, кабы, когда бы, когда б.* Все они, кроме *ли*, имеют вариант с *то* (*если… то, если б(ы)… то* и др.).

> Союзу *если* в значении «положения дел» (см. п. 5.1) синонимичен союз *раз*, который также подает ситуацию X как данное, которое, по мнению Говорящего, «Адресат не будет отрицать» [Иорданская, Мельчук 2007: 495]:
>   (39) *Раз* его так приняли на родине, *раз* сделали преступником, руки не подают, то и ему никто не нужен. [Д. Гранин]
>   Ср. также следующий пример, где *раз* употребляется после *если*, как бы закрепляя гипотезу, которая, будучи повторенной, принимается уже как аксиома:
>   (40) Достоевский полагал, что если Бога нет, то всё дозволено, а *раз* дозволено, то можно и духом пасть, отчаяться. [Д. Гранин]

[Пояснение из пункта 5.1.1: (3) *если* «данного положения дел»: *Если ты, Лелища, съела вторую пастилку, то я еще раз откушу это яблоко* (М. Зощенко) — речь идет о реально имеющей место ситуации, которая вызывает какую-то другую ситуацию.]

[Условные союзы (5.2.)](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%8B#52)
[РАЗ, *союз*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic?all=x&word=%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7)

Получается, что можно и с *уж*, можно и без. Можно и с *то*.

Comment: Спасибо, Римма! Не понял только "ещё раз откушу" — это же совсем другое.

Comment: Артем, это предложение вот отсюда: http://www.razumniki.ru/elka_zoschinko_rasskaz.html?1303822983 ("Ёлка". Рассказы для детей. М. М. Зощенко)

Comment: Хорошо, Римма! Просто смысл другой, количественный. Нет разве?

Comment: Ну-у, не знаю. Это ведь не мое предложение, а Зощенко. И цитирует его не только корпусная грамматика, но и многажды другие авторы.

Comment: А где цитируют в связи с этим, не догнал пока?

Comment: Римма, помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А-а! Поняла. То, что в квадратных скобках (после выделенной ссылки), относится с союзу ЕСЛИ и и дано мной для разъяснения ранее указанного понятия _«положения дел»_. " То я еще раз откушу" к союзу РАЗ не имеет никакого отношения. Прочитайте еще раз, пожалуйста. P. S. Могу изничтожить.

Comment: Ну да, по-моему, это относится к "если", да. Я просто не сразу понял, по какой это ссылке. Так что надо удалить, я думаю. А вот ещё интересно стало, что за Лелища. Лёлища от Лёля или некая Лел**и**ща непонятная? Нет у вас идей?

Comment: (В ответе: см. п. 5.1.)  Лёля — Лёлища; Света — Светища; Марина — Маринища. Это цитата из книги **«Лёля и Минька** (сборник)» Михаила Зощенко. (https://www.livelib.ru/quote/331686-lelya-i-minka-mihail-zoschenko) _Только хотели перекусить, как появилась **Светища.** Ей тоже надоело на крыше веранды книжки читать_ (Е. Хохряков).

Comment: *Лёля — Лёлища.* Значит, я угадал! ;) *Получается, что можно и с уж, можно и без. Можно и с то.* А можно и с тем и с другим.

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрались. И напоследок:  _**Раз уж** вы пришли, **то** давайте поднимемся ко мне..._ (М. Серова)